# how can I generate Java/JSP forms (to work on database data)?

Tags: java, jsp, frameworks, jdbc, crud

I'm searching for good tools to build jsp forms for DB transactions (new, edit, delete of records)
I want to use the simliest tool available.
I don't want to write setters/getters for each single record field and for each single table and for each kind of access (read / change).
Do I need to learn Wicket or JSF to handle this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your keyword is [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) (Create, Read, Update, Delete). [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org) has a [CRUD generator](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html) which can autogenerate JPA 2.0 entities and JSF 2.0 CRUD forms based on just a SQL database table.

Or, if you're more from [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org) (like me), then try the [CRUDO plugin](http://crudo.sourceforge.net/) (I've never tried it though).

Answer (score 1):

You can just use **Spring MVC + JPA** with a **scaffolding tool** (a CRUD generator)

For example, this demo application : http://bookstore-spring.telosys-tools-demo.cloudbees.net/ 
has been created in 1 hour from an existing database by following 
this tutorial : https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/springmvc-jpa-springdatajpa

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it but in a similar vein to BalusC's answer, there is also [SpringFuse](http://www.springfuse.com/) ([more info](http://blog.springfuse.com/2011/02/springfuse-generates-primefaces-with.html)).